# Picasso's placeholder doesn't work

Tags: android, firebase, picasso

I am using Picasso to load images from Firebase Storage into a listview. Each time I scroll, the placeholder doesn't appear before the image is loaded; however, other preloaded image place-hold the Imageview until the image is loaded. How  can I solve that?

This is my part of code:

```
StorageReference mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

mStorage.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {

   @Override
   public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

         Picasso.with(c).load(uri.toString())
        .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
        .into(itemImage);

         }}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {

    @Override
   public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {}
});
```

Comment: Your placeholder image won't be appeared since you're calling it only in onSuccess method. So, the downloaded image is ready to show already. There is no time to show placeholder image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, the problem was that the listener that I was putting to get the URL. I solved it by providing Picasso with a direct URL